# call json via jquery from external file not working

Tags: jquery, json, callback, cross-browser, jsonp

I have this json data in an external file called kw.json:

```
{
"categories" : [{
"producer" : "Apple",
        "items" : [
        {"name": "iPhone 4G"},
        {"name": "iPhone 4GS"},
        {"name": "iPhone 5"}
    ]
},{
"producer" : "Samsung",
        "items" : [
        {"name": "Galaxy S3"},
        {"name": "Galaxy S2"}
    ]
 },{
"producer" : "Nokia",
    "items" : [
        {"name": "Lumia"},
        {"name": "3210"},
        {"name": "3310"}
    ]
}]
```

}

And I have this script loading the file and handling with the data:

```
 var menulist;
 $.getJSON(rootDomain + "kunden/*kwmobile*/js/kw.json", function(json) {
menulist = json;

var i,c = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>bitte Hersteller auswählen</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">', opt = $('<li/>');

var menu = menulist.categories;

for (i=0; i < menu.length; i++){
    c += '<li><span class="noar" id="'+[i]+'">' + menu[i].producer + '</span></li>';
}

$('#cat').html(c+'</ul>');
$(".noar").live('click',function(){
    var indx = $(this).attr("id");
    if (indx < 0) {
        $('#items').css('display','none');
        return;
    }
    var item = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>bitte Modell auswählen</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
    for (i=0; i < menu[indx].items.length; i++){
        item += '<li><span class="pointer search_link" searchkey="'+ menu[indx].producer +' '+ menu[indx].items[i].name +'">' + menu[indx].items[i].name + '</span></li>';
    }

    $('#items').html(item+'</ul>').fadeIn();
    $("#items").menuFlip();
});
 });
```

The problem is, that the console show's an cross-browser error but i have no possibility to upload the .json at the same origin.

I know that jsonp may solve the problem but i never worked with so i hope you can help me.

(sorry for the bda english, i am from germany)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have access to modify the `kw.json` file at the remote location?

Comment: I believe this may be your issue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. you cannot make an ajax call across domain's. the browser won't allow it (full stop)

Comment: yes, that's it...is there a way to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the remote server as well, you would be able to make a JSONP-call, as you indicate. Rather than storing the raw data in `kw.json`, you could wrap the data with a function call:

```
jsonpCallback({ "categories": ... });
```

That way, when the resource is loaded –

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="remote-location/kw.json"></script>
```

– it will call a function named `jsonpCallback` on your site, passing the data. So all you have to do is to create a function to handle the data, and to load the resource. For loading the resource, [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (and hence `getJSON`) has built in JSONP support.

Strictly speaking, your file is a script that constructs a javascript object and passes it to a function, and no longer a plain JSON data file, so it might be neater to call it `kw.js` if that's an option. Of course file names can be arbitrary and mime type is all that matters.

Comment: Thanks David. I will try your solution and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.

The json file wrapped in a function:

```
jsonp123({
"categories" : [{
"producer" : "Apple",
        "items" : [
        {"name": "iPhone 4G"},
        {"name": "iPhone 4GS"},
        {"name": "iPhone 5"}
    ]
},{
"producer" : "Samsung",
        "items" : [
        {"name": "Galaxy S3"},
        {"name": "Galaxy S2"}
    ]
 },{
"producer" : "Nokia",
    "items" : [
        {"name": "Lumia"},
        {"name": "3210"},
        {"name": "3310"}
    ]
}]
});
```

and in my js-file I call jsonp123 to get all the stuff inside:

```
$.ajax({
url: rootDomain + "kunden/*kwmobile*/js/kw.json?callback=json123",
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonpCallback: "jsonp123",
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error);
},
success: function(categories) { 
    jsonp123(categories);
}
});

function jsonp123(response){

var i,c = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>bitte Hersteller auswählen</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">', opt = $('<li/>');

var menu = response.categories;

for (i=0; i < menu.length; i++){
    c += '<li><span class="noar" id="'+[i]+'">' + menu[i].producer + '</span></li>';
}

$('#cat').html(c+'</ul>');
$(".noar").live('click',function(){
    var indx = $(this).attr("id");
    if (indx < 0) {
        $('#items').css('display','none');
        return;
    }
    var item = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>bitte Modell auswählen</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
    for (i=0; i < menu[indx].items.length; i++){
        item += '<li><span class="pointer search_link" searchkey="'+ menu[indx].items[i].name +'">' + menu[indx].items[i].name + '</span></li>';
    }

    $('#items').html(item+'</ul>').fadeIn();
    $("#items").menuFlip();
});
}
```

This works pretty well with no errors.

Thank you for the hints!